# How to compile a project with maven so that it can be debugged from jdb?

Tags: maven, jdb

I am trying to learn `jdb`. I have a maven project. I tried debugging it with `jdb` when I use the `list` command I am not able to see any source code. I get this message:

```
main[1] list
Source file not found: App.java
```

So how should I compile a project with maven so that it can latter be debugged with `jdb` and I can see the source code?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this has nothing to do with `maven`. One of the options `jdb` takes is the `sourcepath` and it is over here you specify the path(s) it will search for the source code.